# Call a function and setQueryTimeout with registerOutParameter using JdbcTemplate / NamedParameterJdbcTemplate

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, jdbctemplate

```
String call = "{ ? = call checkTestAvailability() }";
int intTimeOut = 5000;

try {
    conn = this.jdbcFactory.getConnection();
    cstmt = conn.prepareCall(call);
    cstmt.setQueryTimeout(intTimeOut);
    cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
    cstmt.executeUpdate();
    result = cstmt.getString(1);
} catch () {
    //bla bla
}
```

This is the  old database connection code in the old app. I want this to convert to **JdbcTemplate / NamedParameterJdbcTemplate** style.

I tried to convert this to `JdbcTemplate` like this:

```
String call = "call checkTestAvailability()";
int intTimeOut = 5000;

try {
    jdbc.setQueryTimeout(intTimeOut);
    result = jdbc.queryForObject(call, String.class);
} catch () {
    // bla bla
}
```

However, the result is returning null.
I also need to add the `registerOutParameter` I think but `JdbcTemplate` doesn't have this functionality. Can you suggest a way on how to convert this old code? I think I needed to convert the old code the exact same way.

For this old code statement:

```
cstmt.getString(1);
```

How can I also incorporate this one on the new code?

I am using Spring-Boot and just `Autowired` the **NamedParameterJdbcTemplate /JdbcTemplate**.

Comment: Use the `call` method of the `JdbcTemplate` or use a `SimpleJdbcCall` instead of a `JdbcTemplate`.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have tried "call checkTestAvailability()" for JdbcTemplate but is still returning null, will try SimpleJdbcCall however I don't see setQueryTimeout and registerOutParameter for SimpleJdbcCall

Comment: Ofcourse you won't see those methods as they are named differntly... And no you should try ` call checkTestAvailability` I said that you should use the `JdbcTemplate.call` method ...

Comment: Hi I have used your suggestion for SimpleJdbcCall, and it is now working. Btw, do you know how to setQueryTimeout or any setting of time out for SimpleJdbcCall?
@M.Deinum

Comment: If you want more control use the aformentioned `jdbctemplate.call` method.